# Searching files containing non-ASCII characters

Tags: shell-script, grep, regular-expression, text

I'm trying to find files in a directory that contains some non-ASCII Unicode characters. The exact characters that I have to find are not known to me beforehand.

Conceptually, this should be an easy task -- find all files that match the regex `[^\0-\x7f]`. However, I cannot come up with something that can actually do this.

The closest thing that I could come up with is:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Plv '[\0-\x7f]' {} \;
```

which ends up listing most normal text files due to matches on the blank lines.

The `-e` switch is not allowed in combination with `-P` so I cannot use `-e '[\0-\x7f]' -e '^$'`, and converting the regex to `[\0-\x7f]|^$` would be obviously wrong because now its an "or".

Is there another way to search for such characters?

Answer (score 5):

With `grep -Pv '[\0-\x7f]'`, you're asking for lines that don't (`-v`) contain an ASCII character. That's not the same thing as lines that contain a non-ASCII character. Just ask for that.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -lP '[^\0-\x7f]'
```

Instead of a code point range, you could ask for non-printable characters in an ASCII locale. This is almost equivalent (it also includes control characers).

```
LC_ALL=C grep -l '[^[:print:]]'
```

An equivalent, more complicated way is to search for lines that are entirely made up of ASCII characters and invert the matching.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -vlP '^[\0-\x7f]*$'
```

Comment: Gilles, How about `[[:ASCII:]]`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of them work :( As an experiment, try running these on a local copy of the English and Chinese Wikipedia homepages: Either both are selected or neither are selected.

Comment: Works for me: `LC_ALL=C find . -type f -exec  grep -l '[^[:print:]]' {} \;`

Comment: @user2064000 both English and Chinese Wikipedia home pages contain both ASCII and non-ASCII characters.